# How to check pdf word count with alphanumeric value in php?

Tags: php, word-count

May be encoding issue there when i am fetching text from pdf.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly how this works, but with `explode()` and `count()` you can archieve something like that:

```
$words = count(explode(" ", $string));
```

Example:

```
$string = "Hey i am 21 years old and 165 cm";
$words = count(explode(" ", $string));
echo $words; //returns 9
```

Comment: i used it but not get exact result for some pdfs like pdf i made in apple viewer.

Comment: yes, i messed up the `explode` and swapped the delimiter and the string by accident. Try again with the updated function. Should work now, at least it does for me.

Comment: Can you give me an example string and what exactly you are trying to archive? This is counting all the words in a string, i dont rly know where your actual problem is.

Comment: Actually i have pdf which have 17500 words but here a cant upload it.